# Saving in parquet format from multiple spark workers

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, parquet

I have a job that needs to save the result in parquet/avro format from all the worker nodes. Can I do a separate parquet file for each of the individual partition and read all the resulting files as a single table? Or is there a better way of going about this?
Input is divided into 96 partitions and result needs to be saved on HDFS. When I tried to save it as a file it created over a million small files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `repartition` (or `coalesce` if you always want fewer partitions) to the desired number of partitions just before you call `write`. Your data will then be written into the same number of files. When you want to read in the data, you simply point to the folder with the files rather than to a specific file. Like this:

```
sqlContext.read.parquet("s3://my-bucket/path/to/files/")
```

Comment: It's not in a RDD. Need to save it from JAVA itself.

Comment: As it was a mapped RDD re-partitioning removed a lot of the data. So, now we convert the RDD into Dataframe and then coalesce it to 3.

Comment: Ehm...first off, a mapped RDD is still an RDD. Secondly, calling `repartition` will not remove any data, it will simply shuffle data around into the desired number of partitions. Third, you can indeed use `coalesce` instead of `repartition` (I have updated my answer with this).